# Como puedo llamar el metodo mostrarDatos de la clase hija en mi main? Teniendo en cuenta que hay constructores

Tags: java, poo

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Persona[] persona = new Persona[5];
    persona[0] = new Estudiante("Java Avanzado", "Agustin", "Ozuna", 5445247, EstadoCivil.soltero);
    persona[1] = new Estudiante("Visual Basic", "Gilberto", "Ramirez", 451245, EstadoCivil.soltero);
    persona[2] = new Personal(Seccion.decanato, "Orlando", "Romero", 124578, EstadoCivil.casado);
    persona[3] = new Profesor(Departamento.lenguajes, "Castellano", "Juan", "Cristaldo", 154864, EstadoCivil.viudo);
    persona[4] = new Empleado(2005, TipoDecano.FIUNA, "Brayan", "Caceres", 666644, EstadoCivil.comprometido);
   }
```

---

clase padre persona :

```
public abstract class Persona {

String nombre;
String apellido;
int nroId;
EstadoCivil estadoCivil;

public Persona(String nombre, String apellido, int nroId, EstadoCivil estadoCivil) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.nroId = nroId;
    this.estadoCivil = estadoCivil;
}




public void mostrarDatos() {
    System.out.println("Metodo de la clase padre");

}

}
```

---

Clase estudiante que hereda persona:

```
public class Estudiante extends Persona {

String curso;

public Estudiante(String curso, String nombre, String apellido, int nroId, EstadoCivil estadoCivil) {
    super(nombre, apellido, nroId, estadoCivil);
    this.curso = curso;
}


public String getCurso() {
    return curso;
}

public void setCurso(String curso) {
    this.curso = curso;
}

@Override
public void mostrarDatos() {
    System.out.println("\nNombre: " + nombre + "\nApellido: " + apellido + "\nCedula nro: " + nroId + "\nEstado Civil: " + estadoCivil  
            + "\nCurso: " + curso);

}

}
```

---

Como puedo llamar el metodo mostrarDatos de la clase Estudiante?
E intentado pero no encuentro como llamar al metodo..

Comment: Pero estas sobreescribiendo el metodo.. para que querrias llamar al metodo del padre si lo sobreescribis?

Comment: mmm, entonces debo llamar desde la clase padre?

Comment: Explica que es lo que queres hacer. la clase estudiante ya tiene un metodo mostrar datos, para que queres el del padre?

Comment: Estoy intentando hacer uso de herencia y polimorfismo.

Comment: Ok, y cual es el resultado que esperas al usar esas clases? Sobreescribir mostrarDatos no es ni herencia ni polimorfismo

Comment: Con el array de objetos yo envie los datos a los constructores.Se supone que estan guardados. Bueno, lo que quiero ahora es imprimir todos esos datos. Y creo que con el metodo mostrarDatos es como deberia hacerlo. Es por eso mi pregunta de como llamar el metodo.

Comment: Hay otras clases tambien, como profesor, empleado..Pero quiero hacer la prueba imprimiendo los datos de los estudiantes.Pero no se como.

Comment: En conclusion, quiero imprimir todos esos datos que guarde en el array de objetos..Pero para hacer la prueba solo quiero imprimir el de Estudiante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu planteamiento está bien como lo tienes, suponiendo por supuesto que cada clase hija tiene su método `mostrarDatos()` marcado con `@Override`, puedes leer cada elemento del array así:

```
    for(Persona p : persona){
        p.mostrarDatos();
    }
```

Si sólo quieres mostrar los datos de los `Estudiantes` entonces puedes poner una condición dentro del bucle:

```
    for(Persona p : persona){
        if (p instanceof Estudiante) {
              p.mostrarDatos();
        }
     }
```

En ese caso, sólo invocará al método `mostrarDatos` cuando el elemento `p` del bucle sea una instancia de `Estudiante`.

Lo podemos ver en un ejemplo en el cual se ha creado un array con tres objetos, dos de la clase `Estudiante` y uno de la clase `Profesor`.

La salida, invocando el método `mostrarDatos` por cada elemento del array sería así:

```
Nombre: Agustin
Apellido: Ozuna
Cedula nro: 5445247
Curso: Java Avanzado

Nombre: Gilberto
Apellido: Ramirez
Cedula nro: 451245
Curso: Visual Basic

Nombre: Pedro
Apellido: Pérez
Cedula nro: 755555
Asignatura: Java y Android
```

#### DEMO

Puedes ver aquí un <kbd>**[DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/GKXR52203)**</kbd>

Comment: Guau!!! Muchas gracias, eres muy bueno. Me sirve mucho!!. Es exactamente lo que buscaba.